# Java 8 Diffie Hellman key size issues with 32 bit linux

Tags: java, linux, encryption, diffie-hellman

after upgrading our java from 1.7 to 1.8 on an old 32 bit linux system, we receive the following error message while communicating with a webservice:

> Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: DH key size must be multiple of 64, and can only range from 512 to 2048 (inclusive). The specific key size 4096 is not supported

The linux distribution is:

> uname -a
>
> Linux XXX-XXX-S018 2.6.16.21-0.8-default #1 Mon Jul 3
>   18:25:39 UTC 2006 i686  i686 i386 GNU/Linux

The distribution:

> cat /etc/*release
>
> LSB_VERSION="core-2.0-noarch:core-3.0-noarch:core-2.0-ia32:core-3.0-ia32"
>   SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 10 (i586)
>   VERSION = 10

The Java Version we are using (32 bit and 64 bit the same releases)

> Java Version:
>
> jdk1.8.0_151

The strange thing is, after downgrading to java 1.7 it works without any problems.

Also the same application runs on a different 64 bit system (with java 1.8) - so we assume that this might be an issue with os architecture (32 bit), the age of the os (in this case from 2006) and java.

We found some bug reports regarding the open JDK that the maximum length was 2048 - but we are using the regular JDK from oracle in the moment.

Thanks for your help,

Hauke

Comment: Which specific version of Java 1.8?

Comment: I edited my post - jdk1.8.0_151

Answer (score 0):

please read https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u151-relnotes-3850493.html

in Oracle JRE 8u151 you shall find `java.security` file and set set the *crypto.policy* to a value of `'unlimited'`.

I assume your JRE7 has the Unlimited JRE strength policy already installed

Newer versions (8u161, ..) are having the unlimited strength enabled by default.

Please note Oracle JRE 8u151 has a serious issue with decoding gzip stream. When using with a web/application server such as Tomcat, .. you have to disable stream compression or upgrade to a little bit higher https://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8189789

Comment: The crypto.policy inside the file /jre/lib/security/java.security was already set to unlimited. I also tried it with Java 8u191 without luck.